# Const correctness with Boost iterator_facade

Tags: c++, boost

I'm writing an iterator facade for use with a collection which is wrapped into another class. I followed the tutorial until [telling the truth](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#telling-the-truth), which states:

> Now `node_iterator` and `node_const_iterator` behave exactly as you'd expect... almost. We can compare them and we can convert in one direction: from `node_iterator` to `node_const_iterator`. If we try to convert from `node_const_iterator` to `node_iterator`, we'll get an error when the converting constructor tries to initialize `node_iterator`'s `m_node`, a `node*` with a `node const*`. So what's the problem?

To me this seems exactly what I would want, i.e. not being able to convert a const iterator to a non-const iterator. The conversion being possible, seemingly, would be a failure in const correctness as the iterated node would lose the `const` qualifier.

Am I missing something? I'm asking because some of my code fails to compile and this is one possible reason.

Comment: Did you read the next paragraph, and apply the `enable_if` trick?

Comment: I read it but did not apply it yet. I'm unsure about _why_ I should do it.

Comment: The article says exactly what the problem is, on the very next line (literally).

Comment: I gave it a shot but apparently the underlying problem is somewhere else. However, I'm still having trouble understanding, what exactly the said trick is supposed to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just stop reading half-way through the chapter. The very next lines of the source material tell you why this is a problem: we want the conversion itself to not exist. As it is, the conversion exists, but fails someway up the call stack in the innards of the implementation, which results in less than clear diagnostics, and a broken `boost::is_convertible<node_const_iterator,node_iterator>` trait.

Comment: Thanks, the way I understood the first chapter was that the user's intention would be to convert a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`. Now the whole section makes more sense.

Comment: The sentence “By rewriting the converting constructor as follows, we can remove it from the overload set when it's not appropriate” should have made it clear, though.

Comment: @tsnorri: Like much of the Boost documentation, it's admittedly not very clear. :)